# Codeigniter 3.0.5 Session is not working in online

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have deployed a codeigniter project to production server.In local it is working fine with session and no issues found ,but it moved to production then its session is not working. It moved into a subdirectory of main domain i.e ****public_html/demo/project/**  Any advice would be appreciable.

Comment: whats your domain address ?

Comment: Friend that I cant disclose .I put my project  public_html/demo/food_master

Comment: Is there any mapping issues

Comment: probably permission problems. the folder that CodeIgniter will save the session data has to give write permissions

Comment: please check your base url in config.php make sure `"http://www."` is there in your base url

Comment: sounds like either a permissions issue or server misconfiguration can you tell us more about the permissions of your folder?

Comment: When I put the project in the Level of Demo ie. "public_html/project" then Session get works fine.BUt it is not Unknown why the session not working public_html/demo/project" may be the .htaccess issue. I have given the cpanel files with 644 Permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue raised because the difference in php in local and with production server.It could corrected by changing the php version of cpanel matching  with local which had initially coded